# iPhone app memory related query

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am building an iPhone application .In the database I have 5000 records. Among them I am displaying only 50 in the app. But I want to ask would there be any memory issue if I create 5000 empty cells in the iPhone view initially even though I am displaying 50 rows of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build your table appropriately, you will only be using a handful to perhaps a dozen actual UITableViewCell objects which are constantly recycled as things show on screen.

Even 50 would be safe.

Having 5000 data objects in memory with 50 UITableViewCells should be pretty acceptable.

Especially if those data objects are small, or you are allowing CoreData to do some work for you with managing your data set.

The important thing is DO NOT MAKE 5000 TABLE CELL VIEWS. That is extremely poor practice.

Answer (score 1):

iPhone has a limited amount of memory so you should always be careful to display only the data that is necessary for that view. You can implement infinite scrolling where when you reach the bottom of the screen through scrolling you trigger an event and load the next 25-50 records.

http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/8-automatic-uitableview-paging

Answer (score 1):

One thing you'll quickly learn with the [canonical way of handling tables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW5) is that regardless of the size of your model (i.e., the number of rows you intend to create), only a handful of rows are actually created, therefore the memory footprint remains low.

In essence, the UITableView initially creates and renders a screenful of rows (plus a few more for good measure). When you begin scrolling down, the controller recognises that it needs to draw a new row. But, it also realises that rows from the top of the table have disappeared from view. So, rather than create a whole new cell it simply takes one of the cells no longer in view and reconfigures it with the new info. No matter how many rows your table has, only those few cells live in memory.

So in your case, the memory bottleneck will likely be the model that is feeding the cell configuration. If you loaded all your 5000 rows into memory at once then that may be slow and memory consuming. But there is help at hand: you get a hint from the table controller that basically tells you that it wants to set up the *n*th row. So your model can in effect be more targeted and only load the data you need. E.g., since you know the 15th row is being rendered, then go and grab the 15th row from your database rather than preloading the entire model up-front.

This is the approach I've used to create apps with many more than 5000 rows without the need for paging. Of course it depends on your dataset as to how your user may navigate.